# two sub query in sql

Tags: query-optimization, h2db

I am working on an application in which I have to retrieve min and max date from `DATETIME` Column and then set min and max value to JSlider.

My Date format present in database : `2017-06-22T03:16:26Z`

But I only want date in two formats `20170622031626` AND `20170622`

I have tried some sql query but doesn't get the required results.

Here are two query I am using :

```
SELECT DISTINCT( REPLACE("DATETIME",'-','') ) FROM CDR WHERE DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(DATETIME) FROM CDR)
```

OUTPUT: 20170501T00:00:00Z

```
select min(replace(replace(replace(replace("DATETIME",'-',''),'T',''),'Z',''),':','')) FROM CDR
```

OUTPUT: 20170501000000

The second query gives the one of the required results but how can I get only `20170501` ?

Any idea how can I achieve the required results ??

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: ok, Thanks. I will keep in mind for future

Comment: If sql server then `convert(varchar(8),cast('2017-06-22T03:16:26Z' as datetime),112)`

Comment: I have updated the question, I am using h2Database